# Detached App Push Notification Example (FCM and APNS)

Tags: apple-push-notifications, expo, react-native-fcm

I created an Expo app and it works great on both iOS and Android. Now I’d like to detach the app and use FCM and APNS for push notifications. Does anyone know of a really good example that shows in detail the process to change a detached Expo app to one that relies on FCM and APNS to receive push notifications on both iOS and Android?

Comment: were you able to find a solution ?

Comment: No, not yet. Any advice would be appreciated.